# Inconsistent behaviour when impossible intersections produce `never` type

Tags: typescript

I found that TypeScript produces `never` type at different levels when impossible intersections happen

```
type Foo = {name: string, age: string}
type Bar = {name: string, age: number}

type Baz = Foo & Bar
const baz: Baz = {name: '123,', age:13} // ❌ Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

The above example results in type `Baz` to be `{name: string, age:never}`

However if we slightly change `Bar`

```
type Foo = {name: string, age: string}
type Bar = {name: string, age: boolean}

type Baz = Foo & Bar // the whole `Baz` type is `never`
```

Now the whole `Baz` type is `never`. I cannot figure out as to why TypeScript did this. Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: It might be because boolean is a union and ts has some strategy for this case

Comment: As examples for the comment above, using specific strings or numbers, such as `{name: string, age: string} & {name: string, age: 0 | 1}` or `{name: string, age: 'one' | 'two'} & {name: string, age: number}`, also narrows the whole intersection to `never`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before TypeScript 3.9, both intersections would behave like your first example and be equivalent to `{name: string, age: never}`.  TypeScript 3.9 introduced functionality to [reduce intersections by *discriminant* properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#intersections-reduced-by-discriminant-properties).  Discriminant properties are, roughly, those whose values are of single [literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) types (like string literal types, numeric literal types, boolean literal types, `null`, and `undefined`) or [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of such types.  These are used in [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  If an intersection type causes a discriminant property to reduce to `never`, the compiler will reduce the whole intersection to `never`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#36696](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36696) for details and motivation.

Anyway, the type `boolean` is represented as the union `true` | `false` of boolean literals, and therefore the `age` property in your second example is considered to be a discriminant property.  On the other hand, `number` is a non-literal type and so the `age` property in your first example is *not* considered to be a discriminant property.  This accounts for the difference in behavior you are seeing.

Comment: ahh I see... so the logic here is that if the disjoint (disjointed?) properties happen to be literal types, which can be discriminant, the whole thing is reduced to `never` but if the disjoint properties are non-literal types then only those properties are reduced to `never`?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what happens.

Comment: Just curious about the terminologies here: if we have a `type Foo = {name: string, age: string}` and another type `Bar = {name: number, age: string}`. Is the mismatched `name` property called disjoint property or is it the two types called disjoint types?